# shortcut to select data to the last row

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-macros

I'm new to Emacs. First of all sorry if my English is weird because it is not my first language. I don't know much about the terminologies used in Emacs.
Currently, I'm just using Emacs for data processing for my undergraduate journal research.

I recently wondered how to select data inside highlighted part (either `C-SPC` or `C-X-SPC`) and then instead of pressing the down arrow to the last row, maybe there is a shortcut to do that.

As the title says, is there a shortcut to select data to the last row?

If I fail to explain this, I think the best way to comprehend is like in excel:
when you press the **SHIFT+Down arrow**, you will automatically select the first and last filled row.

Answer (score 1):

After using `C-SPC` to define the start of your region, You can use `M->` to expand the selection to the last row.

According to Emacs help:

`M->` runs the command `end-of-buffer`

which is bound to the key combinations: `M->` and `C-end`.

Note: similarly, `M-<` lets you to go to the first line.